# Read what passed to generic from value of an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, react-navigation

#### BACKGROUND

I want to make abstraction out of react navigation but couldn't get the types work correctly

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  HomeTab: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabParamList>;
  DetailsScreen: {
    id: string;
  };
};
```

i want to provide the information of my screens inside an array

```
const screens = [
  {
    name: "HomeTab",
    component: HomeTab
  },
  {
    name: "DetailsScreen",
    component: DetailsScreen,
    options: ({route}) => ({
      // in this case i couldn't get the correct types
      title: route.id ? `Details with ${id}`: "Details"
    })

  }
]
```

The only thing i want to achieve is to type above array correctly.

i'm able to achieve some of it with below explanation

I have this type from react navigation where it will read screen props based on screen name passed into its generic

```
type RootScreenProps<
  T extends keyof RootStackParamList = keyof RootStackParamList,
> = RouteConfig<
  RootStackParamList,
  T,
  StackNavigationState<RootStackParamList>,
  NativeStackNavigationOptions,
  NativeStackNavigationEventMap
>;
```

like this

```
type DetailsScreenProps = RootScreenProps<"DetailsScreen">
```

but i'm having trouble using it in object since it can't read what data being passed to object

```
const screen: RootScreenProps<I_WANT_THIS_TO_READ_THE_VALUE_OF_THE_NAME_KEY_BELOW> = {
  name: 'DetailsScreen',
  component: CompTest,
  options: ({route}) => {
    return {
      title: route.params.id,
    };
  },
};
```

is there a way to do this in typescript??

The only possible hack i can think of is creating a function from it

like this

```
const createScreen = <T extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
  props: RootScreenProps<T>,
): RootScreenProps<T> => {
  return props;
};
```

and using it like this

this will be correctly typed

```
const screen = createScreen({name: 'DetailsScreen', options: {title: 'Test'}});
```

but i don't want to use / pass it as a function.

Comment: Why you need to read the key? This is resolved during compile time. The code will be transpiled to javascript and this key just doesn't exist in your final code (not as a run time information). So why do you need it? Can you do something like: for (x in yourClass) { // x is the key?? }

Comment: route.params.id, <- id in this case is dynamic based on what value provided in the name. if i provide other than `DetailsScreen` it won't have that id

Comment: i updated my question with a background to what i want to achieve